# Search indexes in data.table R

Tags: r, list, data.table, match

I have a data.table, `proce`, where each line defines a "special procedure". Now, I have another data.table with the patient procedures, `codes`. For each person, I want to extract the indexes of "special procedures" that match with his/her procedures (if they have any). Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
proce <- data.table(v1 = c('o09513','o721','o701','z370'), v2 = c('0w8nxzz','10d07z6','0tqd7zz','0uqg0zz'),
                         v3 = c('3e030vj','3e033vj',NA,NA))

codes <- data.table(a1 =  c(list(c('o721','10d07z6','3e033vj')),
                            list(c('z370','0uqg0zz',"0tqd7zz","o701")),
                            list(c('o09513','o721','o701','z370','0uqg8zz'))))
```

```
> proce
       v1      v2      v3
1: o09513 0w8nxzz 3e030vj
2:   o721 10d07z6 3e033vj
3:   o701 0tqd7zz    <NA>
4:   z370 0uqg0zz    <NA>

> codes
                              a1
1:          o721,10d07z6,3e033vj
2:     z370,0uqg0zz,0tqd7zz,o701
3: o09513,o721,o701,z370,0uqg8zz
```

Implementation here, but since both tables have hundred thousands of lines, it's slow.

```
index_procedures <- list()     
for(i in 1:nrow(codes)){ # i <- 2
  a2 <- unlist(codes[i,a1])
  index_procedures[[i]] <- which(apply(proce[,.(v1,v2,v3)], 1,function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% a2)))
}
index_procedures
> index_procedures
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

- `codes` contains procedure steps which have been applied to a patient. One row in `codes` refers to one patient.
- `proce` contains procedure steps which constitute a *special procedure*.

The OP wants to identify which special procedures have been applied on each patient (if any). Thereby, a special procedure is only considered to have been applied on a patient if *all* of its procedure steps have applied.

To solve this, I suggest to reshape all data in *a tidy format*, i.e., in long format, first.

Then we can join on procedure steps, filter for *complete* special procedures and aggregate to get one per patient:

```
lc <- codes[, cid := .I][, .(step = unlist(a1)), by = cid]
lp <- melt(proce[, pid := .I], "pid", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "step")[
  , n_steps := .N, by = pid][]
lp[lc, on = .(step)][
  , .N == first(n_steps), by = .(cid, pid)][
    (V1), .(pid = toString(sort(pid))), by = cid]
```

> ```
>    cid  pid
> 1:   1    2
> 2:   2 3, 4
> ```

Note that the `pid`s are shown in a condensed form for demonstration only; other output formats are available as well depending on subsequent processing steps.

If it is required to show *all* patients even if they have not received a special procedure:

```
lp[lc, on = .(step)][, .N == first(n_steps), by = .(cid, pid)][
  V1 | is.na(V1), .(pid = toString(sort(pid))), by = cid]
```

> ```
>    cid  pid
> 1:   1    2
> 2:   2 3, 4
> 3:   3
> ```

#### Commented code

```
# reshape data to long format, thereby adding a row number to identify patients
lc <- codes[, cid := .I][, .(step = unlist(a1)), by = cid]
# reshape data to long format, thereby adding a row number to identify special procdures
lp <- melt(proce[, pid := .I], "pid", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "step")[
  # count the number of procedure steps which constitute a special procedure
  , n_steps := .N, by = pid][]
# join on procedure steps
lp[lc, on = .(step)][
  # group  by patient and special procedure and test for completeness of steps 
  , .N == first(n_steps), by = .(cid, pid)][
    # filter for complete special procedures and aggregate to get one row per patient
    (V1), .(pid = toString(sort(pid))), by = cid]
```

After reshaping, `lc` is

> ```
>     cid    step
>  1:   1    o721
>  2:   1 10d07z6
>  3:   1 3e033vj
>  4:   2    z370
>  5:   2 0uqg0zz
>  6:   2 0tqd7zz
>  7:   2    o701
>  8:   3  o09513
>  9:   3    o721
> 10:   3    o701
> 11:   3    z370
> 12:   3 0uqg8zz
> ```

and `lp` is

> ```
>     pid variable    step n_steps
>  1:   1       v1  o09513       3
>  2:   2       v1    o721       3
>  3:   3       v1    o701       2
>  4:   4       v1    z370       2
>  5:   1       v2 0w8nxzz       3
>  6:   2       v2 10d07z6       3
>  7:   3       v2 0tqd7zz       2
>  8:   4       v2 0uqg0zz       2
>  9:   1       v3 3e030vj       3
> 10:   2       v3 3e033vj       3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performance, but the following code might be an alternative:

```
pl <- split(as.matrix(proce), seq_len(nrow(proce)))
pl <- lapply(pl, na.omit)

codes[, indexes := lapply(a1, function(x) which(unlist(lapply(pl, function(p) all(p %in% x)))) )]
```